# What do I do with my keychains?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

I went for a walk with my dog, and found a Leather Keychain in the street. I picked it up and took it home, but I really have no idea what to do with it. My dog can't use it for anything.

Is it just trash? Or does it actually have a purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leather keychain can be used as a toy or recycled for items at Mr. Recycle.

Here is a list of items that can be created and the requirements for each:

```
Keyboard (1x Metal, 1x Leather, 1x Plastic, 1x Wood)
Fishbowl (2x Wood, 2x Leather, 2x Plastic)
Combat Copter (2x Metal, 2x Rubber, 2x Plastic)
White Leash (1x Rubber, 1x Plastic)
Telephone Record (1x Leather, 1x Plastic)
Rubber Dumbbell (2x Rubber)
Rainbow Disc (2x Wood, 3x Leather, 2x Plastic, 1x Stardust)
Club Dog Record (1x Leather, 1x Plastic)
Rainbow Ring (3x Leather, 1x Stardust)
Rainbow Lure (2x Wood, 3x Leather, 2x Plastic, 1x Stardust)
Party Hat (2x Wood, 3x Rubber, 1x Stardust)
Rainbow Wig (3x Wood, 2x Rubber, 1x Stardust)
Strawberry Hood (1x Wood, 3x Rubber, 4x Leather)
Koopa-Shell Chair (3x Wood, 2x Metal, 3x Plastic)
Cat Tower (3x Wood, 2x Metal, 1x Rubber)
```

Comment: Recycled for items?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the item list and the required recyclable items. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: ....now I really want the Koopa shell chair.....